# discord.js how to edit/update embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a "small" bot for fun and currently trying to create a blackjack command. The first half works fine, but the problem appears when I want to update the embed that was already posted by the bot. I keep getting an error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user`
Here is part of the code:

```
        const embd = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Dealer cards: ' + botCards + ' + ?'},
                { name: 'Your cards: ' + userCards},
            )

            message.channel.send(embd).then(embdReact => {
                embdReact.react('');
                embdReact.react('');

                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return ['',''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                };
            
                embdReact.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000})
                    .then(collected => {
                        const reaction = collected.first();
            
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
                            const newEmbd = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setTitle("Wow");
                            message.edit(newEmbd);
                        }
                        else {
                            message.reply('boo');
                        }
                        })
            })
```

For testing I tried to change just the title, but in the perfect world a corresponding field would be updated. **Ex:** "Your cards:" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're editing the wrong message :

The line :

```js
message.edit(newEmbd);
```

should be :

```js
embdReact.edit(newEmbd);
```

Hope this will help you to fix your issue !